# Kafka logs deleted even after setting log.retention.ms = -1

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I'm running a hyperledger fabric 1.2.0 network with 5 Kafkas and 3 Zookeepers.

The issue I'm facing is even after setting `log.retention.ms = -1`, Kafka deleted few initial logs. To my knowledge, after setting the above value to -1 guarantees forever persistence of logs.

I set the below config for Kafkas in `docker-compose.yaml`.

```
kafka0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka:amd64-0.4.13
    container_name: kafka0
    environment:
        - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
        - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
        - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
        - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
        - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
        - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
        - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
    ports:
        - 9000:9092
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Similar config for other Kafka containers. Below is the config which I get when I restart any of my Kafka containers.

```
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 3
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    compression.type = producer
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 3
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name =
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 1.0-IV0
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = null
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.format.version = 1.0-IV0
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = -1
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
    message.max.bytes = 103809024
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 2
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 103809024
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
```

My kafka version is `1.13.0`. Below are the logs that you may find helpful and relevant to the question.

```
INFO Incrementing log start offset of partition mychannel-0 to 30457 in dir /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Cleared earliest 0 entries from epoch cache based on passed offset 30457 leaving 6 in EpochFile for partition mychannel-0 (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
INFO Updated PartitionLeaderEpoch. New: {epoch:13, offset:8621}, Current: {epoch:12, offset8618} for Partition: mychannel1-0. Cache now contains 5 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
INFO Found deletable segments with base offsets [0,4883,7464,22368,25071,26892] due to log start offset 30457 breach (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 0 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 4883 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 7464 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 22368 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 25071 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Scheduling log segment 26892 for log mychannel-0 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 0 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 4883 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 7464 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 22368 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 25071 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting segment 26892 from log mychannel-0. (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000026892.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000022368.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000026892.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000022368.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000025071.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000000000.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000007464.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000004883.index.deleted (kafka.log.OffsetIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000025071.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000000000.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000007464.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
INFO Deleting index /tmp/kafka-logs/mychannel-0/00000000000000004883.timeindex.deleted (kafka.log.TimeIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/),

> **`log.cleaner.enable`**  Enable the log cleaner process to run on the server. Should be enabled if using any topics with a
>   cleanup.policy=compact including the internal offsets topic. If
>   disabled those topics will not be compacted and continually grow in
>   size.

I would suggest to set

```
log.cleaner.enable=false
```

and restart your Kafka cluster.

However, this will have an effect even on internal Kafka topics. Alternatively, you could try to disable retention only for the topic of interest:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeperHost:2181 --alter --topic mytopic --config retention.ms=-1
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeperHost:2181 --alter --topic mytopic --config retention.hours=-1
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeperHost:2181 --alter --topic mytopic --config retention.bytes=-1
```

PS: In your logs I can see that `log.retention.hours` is set to `168` and maybe this is the reason why `log.retention.ms=-1` is not effective.

Comment: Doesn't setting log.retention.ms = -1 overrides log.retention.hours? log.retention.hours =168 is the default value but I have overridden it. Plus containers were spawned 2 months ago and the logs purging started a few days ago. 168 hours means 7 days. Apparently, this isn't the case.

Comment: Could you shed some light on log.cleaner.enable=false. What it does and how will it affect the containers? Now that we know retention.hours=168 isn't the case, is log.cleaner.enable=false even relevant to the problem?

Comment: @KartikChauhan Yes, `log.cleaner.enable` is relevant to log compaction.

Comment: But my retention.policy is set to 'delete'. Setting it to compact might be the right step in the future but what about the current case? I don't get why Kafka pruned the previous logs?

Comment: Can you describe the topic and share the output?

Comment: Topic:qamychannel       PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: qamychannel      Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,0,1 Isr: 3,1,0

Answer (score 0):

Kafka would expire or delete messages based on two factors

1. log.retention period (this can be in hours,minutes or ms)
   and
2. log.retention bytes

If any of the criteria is met logs would be purged.